# logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) does not make logger.info() visible

Tags: python, logging

I am working on Python 3.4.2 under Windows. In my case,

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info('test')
```

shows nothing on the console. But

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
logger.info('test')
```

sucessfully shows

```
INFO:logger:test
```

I expected `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` would allow the same printout as in the second code snippet where the logger level is controlled by the root logger but it doesn't. So where's the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a Handler to the logger. The call to `basicConfig` is one way to do that.

There are [many kinds of Handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html). A StreamHandler prints to the console, but there are also FileHandlers, SocketHandlers, and SMTPHandlers for instance. If you don't specify any handlers, the records aren't handled and nothing gets emitted.

---

To add a StreamHandler (without calling basicConfig) you could use:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(console)
logger.info('test')
```

This adds the StreamHandler to the logger named `logger`. To add the handler to the root logger, use

```
logging.root.addHandler(console)
```

By setting the Handler on the root logger, the StreamHandler may handle records generated by other loggers than just `logger`. Consult [the logging flow diagram](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) for a picture of when that happens.

---

Comment: With py3.6.4 on macOS, I added many handlers with their own log levels. However, `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` is still required for my handlers to show INFO/DEBUG level messages.